# How to escape apostrophe successfully in jQuery on iPhone that has Smart Punctuation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I haven't been able to successfully escape Apostrophe on iPhone. After some research, it seems the Smart Punctation feature is causing some issues here. I've tried everything I can find and nothing has worked.

A user is entering text into a field and I verify if this text is correct. Here is my jQuery code. The valid Text is EMPORER'S EYE or Emporer's Eye, but neither ever comes up as valid on iPhone.

```
$("#actionButton").click(function() {
var seats = $("#number2").val();
var apostrophe = '\u0027';
var error = null;


if ((seats === "EMPORER\'S EYE") || (seats === 'Emporer\'s Eye')) {
 $("#message").fadeIn();
   $("#draggable").fadeOut();
  $("#draggable2").fadeOut();
} else {
  $("#messageWrong").fadeIn().delay(2500).fadeOut();
     $("#draggable").fadeOut().delay(2500).fadeIn();
  $("#draggable2").fadeOut().delay(2500).fadeIn();
}


// If you really need setflag:
var setflag = error != null;
});
```

Here is a codepen I have of the entire function and process I'm trying to put together.
https://codepen.io/MaxwellR/pen/BaYGPJL

Comment: You probably mean that the iPhone puts another kind of an apostrophe there. May I ask why you even compare these strings? What is your app doing?

Comment: @RoboRobok I'm verifying the user has entered the specific text to then display a hidden message. Do you know how to account for the different apostrophes that iPhone enters? I haven't written any code in a few years, so it seems this issue may have started around 2019-2020.

Comment: Is this some kind of a game? It's unusual to make people write entire string like that, but if it's 100% justified, I'll add an answer how I'd do it.

Comment: @RoboRobok it's an interactive treasure hunt type thing. So idk if I would define it as a game, but a gamified way to move the user along a path.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make user experience less frustrating, I would skip on checking the special characters, as this is a slippery slope.

You can convert both input and expected value to certain format that allows some degree of liberty in how people spell things. Consider this example:

```js
const sanitizeString = string => string
    .trim() // remove surrounding whitespace
    .toLowerCase() // ignore the case
    .replaceAll(/[^\p{L}\s]/gu, '') // cut out all special characters
    .replaceAll(/\s+/g, ' '); // convert any consecutive whitespace to a space
```

This can be a good balance between being correct and having some freedom to spell things differently.

```js
const string = 'Emporer\'s Eye';
const sanitizedString = sanitizeString(string);
// sanitizedString is now "emporers eye"
```

In your case, you could have a single value inside the condition and it would work:

```js
if (sanitizedString(seats) === sanitizedString('Emporer\'s Eye')) {
    // some magic
}
```